# How to Convert Centesimal to Sexagesimal

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have this query: I need convert the centesimal value from the database to sexagesimal (minutes)

```
SELECT 
DISTINCT RD_MAT,
SUM(CASE WHEN RD_PD IN ('421') THEN RD_HORAS ELSE 0 END) AS 'ATRASOS',
SUM(CASE WHEN RD_PD IN ('420') THEN RD_HORAS ELSE 0 END) AS 'FALTAS',
SUM(CASE WHEN RD_PD IN ('084') THEN RD_HORAS ELSE 0 END) AS 'H.EXTRA 100%',
SUM(CASE WHEN RD_PD IN ('080') THEN RD_HORAS ELSE 0 END) AS 'H.EXTRA 50% ',
SUM(CASE WHEN RD_PD IN ('082') THEN RD_HORAS ELSE 0 END) AS 'H.EXTRA NOTURNA' 
FROM SRD020 
INNER JOIN SRV020 ON RD_PD = RV_COD
   AND SRV020.D_E_L_E_T_ <> '*'
   AND SRD020.D_E_L_E_T_ <> '*'
   AND RD_MAT = '000123'
WHERE LEFT(RD_DATPGT,6) = '201304'
GROUP BY RD_MAT
```

The return of H.EXTRA 100% in centesimal is 16:53. But in minutes is 16:49.

Example: 40 + 40 = 80 in centesimal. 40 + 40 = 1:20 in sexagesimal. I need this value.

Answer (score 0):

So, it looks like you're going for something like this.  I'm casting to VARCHAR for output purposes, which you of course do not have to do.

```
DECLARE @value1 INT, @value2 INT

SET @value1 = 40
SET @value2 = 50

SELECT CAST(FLOOR((@value1+@value2)/60) AS VARCHAR(50)) + ':' +  CAST((@value1+@value2)%60 AS VARCHAR(50))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Declare @h Varchar(5)='16:53'

Select Cast(DateAdd(SS,CAST(REPLACE(@h,':','.') as Float)*60,0) as Time)

>>> 00:16:31.0000000
```